# Como exibir nome do objeto no template do Django?

Tags: python, django

Olá!

Estou em um processo de aprendizagem do Django, na realidade, comecei faz pouquíssimo tempo e estou encontrando dificuldades ao encontrar uma forma de exibir o nome da editora que é uma ForeignKey. Seguem os códigos abaixo:

Meu models.py

```
    titulo_livro = models.CharField(
        max_length = 45
        )
    subtitulo_livro = models.CharField(
        max_length = 45,
        null = True,
        blank = True
        )
sinopse_livro = models.TextField(
        max_length = 1000
        )
    avaliacao_livro = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits = 2,
        decimal_places = 2
        )
    isbn_livro = models.CharField(
        max_length = 13
    ) 
    publicacao_livro = models.DateField(
        auto_now = False,
        auto_now_add = False
        )
    editora_cod_editora = models.ForeignKey(
        'Editora',
        on_delete = models.CASCADE
        )
    categoria_cod_categoria = models.ForeignKey(
        'Categoria',
        on_delete = models.CASCADE
        )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Livros'

# CLASSE PARA A CRIAÇÃO DA TABELA DE EDITORAS    
class Editora(models.Model):
    nome_editora = models.CharField(
        max_length = 45
        )
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'editora'
```

Meu forms.py

```
class LivrosFormulario(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Livros
        fields = ['titulo_livro','subtitulo_livro','sinopse_livro','avaliacao_livro','isbn_livro','publicacao_livro','editora_cod_editora','categoria_cod_categoria',]
```

A view.py que estou penando para entender

```
def livro(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LivrosFormulario(request.POST or None)
        e = Editora.objects.values('nome_editora')
        print(form.errors)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("form é válido")
            try:
                form.save()
                print("form salvo")
                return redirect('/mostrar')
            except:
                print("form não salvo")
                pass
        else:
            print("form não é válido")
    else:
        form = LivrosFormulario()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form':form})
```

E o Template index.html que deveria exibir o nome da editora, mas aparece apenas o id

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form" action="/livro">

      {% csrf_token %}

      <!-- forms que estão funcionando não vou colar aqui-->

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Editora do Livro:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
              {{ form.editora_cod_editora }}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Categoria do Livro:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            {{ form.categoria_cod_categoria }}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
```

Edit: Minha página fica assim:

[image: imagem mostrando o id da editora ao invés de mostrar o nome]

Será que poderiam me dar alguma luz? Estou batendo a cabeça nisso faz um tempão kkkkk

Para informação: Estou usando a última versão estável do Django e do Python

Grata!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça uma def **str**(self): dentro da classe do model da editora depois retorne o self.nome_editora 
o models ficara mais ou menos assim:

```
class Editora(models.Model):
    nome_editora = models.CharField(
        max_length = 45
        )
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'editora'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome_editora
```

Answer (score 0):

Acrescente à classe `Editora` o método`__str__()`, algo assim:

```py
class Editora(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome_editora
```

Isto fará com que o **Django** saiba como representar corretamente este objeto.